# styles.xml is not working as intended

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**Context:**

I recently started trying to learn how to develop very simple Android apps, and have been following many different tutorials and resources available online. I was looking at an exercise that showed how you can use additional `xml` files, such as `styles.xml` to apply a certain style to something without having to copy and paste the same code in the `main.axml` multiple times. So for example, if you have many Buttons, you can apply one general style to all those buttons.

**Problem:**
I have created this app that does nothing, I just wanted to experiment with combing layouts and getting a feel for things. It has 4 buttons (that don't click as yet). This is how it looks, followed by the `main.axml` code.

[image: android_ui_1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calculator_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:text="0" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#ff3f51b5"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="1st"
            android:onClick="ButtonClick" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#F44336"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="2nd"
            android:onClick="ButtonClick" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#ff9c27b0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="3rd"
            android:onClick="ButtonClick" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background="#ff4caf50"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="4th"
            android:onClick="ButtonClick" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I tried applying a 'style' to the buttons because they have a lot of the same properties, and it will make the code simpler and easier to read. This is how I applied the style:

```
<Button
   style="@style/button_style"
   android:background="#ff3f51b5"
   android:text="1st"/>
<Button
   style="@style/button_style"
   android:background="#F44336"
   android:text="2nd"/>
<Button
   style="@style/button_style"
   android:background="#ff9c27b0"
   android:text="3rd"/>
<Button
   style="@style/button_style"
   android:background="#ff4caf50"
   android:text="4th"/>
```

And this is what's in `styles.xml`:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="button_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_rowWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">ButtonClick</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And finally how the UI looks. As evident, none of the button attributes from `styles` got carried over :

[image: 2nd]

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know I probably won't ever need to do this with buttons but I guess it could be helpful for something else later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your **button_style** extend as

```
 parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button"
```

full style would be

```
<style name="button_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_rowWeight">1</item>
<item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
<item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately that did not fix the problem (I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, it still looks like how it was before).

Comment: keep your **android:layout_rowWeight** and **android:layout_columnWeight** in main.xml and give it a try again.

Comment: Hmmm, I mean that works but that sort of defeated my purpose which was to not rewrite the same code many times. Maybe that problem only applies to weights then ? Anyway, thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: Yes, just because those style attributes are directly related to **GridLayout**. So you would need to put them in main.xml as main attribute